# Am I supposed to have no idea what's going on in the first few hours of play?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

I've been playing for a while now, I'm apparently looking for a girl or something, but unless I missed it, there was absolutely no introduction to who I am, or what I am doing, what I'm looking for, where I am, what any of this is.

Have I missed something (perhaps cos I didn't play the earlier bioshock games?)  or am I supposed to have no idea what's going on?

Comment: This will all make sense in hindsight, don't worry.

Comment: I too found the beginning of the game incredibly confusing, but I felt it added to the sense of immersion. I felt almost as confused as I assume I might were I to sit in a dentist chair in a lighthouse that subsequently became a rocket to a city in the clouds. Take a page out of Booker's book - steady on, stay alive, and get the girl.

Comment: It's hard to be immersed when I feel I'm just gunning down innocent people for no reason. I'll stick with it though, the visuals and the looting are fun.

Comment: What makes you feel like you're just gunning down "innocent people"?

Comment: Basically the game starts with me on a boat, I have no idea who I am or what I'm doing, then I end up in this city in the sky, they are gonna stone a couple of people to death so I then decide to just start killing hundreds of people because I don't like their customs, none of whom have done bad to me, they're just doing their job of protecting the people in the city. Then I'm kidnapping one of their citizens for reasons unknown whilst still mowing down loads of them. I feel like *I* am the bad guy, but I just don't know what's going on.

Comment: @SLC, the scene where they're going to stone the interracial couple was supposed to convince you that there's a lot of racism at work in the city.  There's an undercurrent of slavery/mistreatment of workers (the Vox Populi) and Comstock's kind of got some world domination plans which he will elaborate on.  Meanwhile, Elizabeth is held, isolated and experimented on, in a tower prison.  Whether or not you find those things objectionable is subject to your own opinion, but if you don't, you're unlikely to understand the game, I'm afraid.

Comment: Sure, I get that. But that's just normal for the time period. Can't go murdering people because I disagree with them then continue murdering the police who come to stop me with a clear concience though. It's weird how I've only ever experienced this in this game. I guess because I don't feel like a hero trying to save the day? Who knows.

Comment: A game is making you think and question your morality! What a world we live in! ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Bioshock: Infinite starts [in medias res](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_medias_res).  There are a lot of details of the "hows" and "whys" that will be explained as you play.

From the outset, you should know that the player character is Booker DeWitt, a private detective who has been hired by a pair of rather unusual people to retrieve a rather unusual girl from a rather unusual city.

The game is quite linear, so there's little to no chance that you'll get lost and not be able to figure out what to do next.  Just keep following along, and eventually the plot will start to come into focus.

However, the plot can be relatively difficult to understand, so I won't go so far as to say that eventually things will make sense :)

There is little to no dependency between Bioshock 1/2 and Infinite.  If you haven't played the first two, you might miss out on some understanding of a few late game moments, but it's nothing major.  I believe the "Burial at Sea" DLC is more tightly tied to Bioshock 1, so you might want to play that game first if you plan on playing the DLC.

Comment: Phew, that's ok then. I am finding it hard to really care about the game though, like running through an exploding building to save someone, I have no idea why I'm there, who I'm saving, where I am, why they're a prisoner, why I'm saving them etc. so I don't feel any kind of tension or sense of urgency :(

Comment: @SLC, I added some basic info about who you are and what the job is to the answer, in case that's not clear to you.  If you don't really feel invested now, chances are the plot twists that are coming aren't going to make much sense, unfortunately.  The original Bioshock was famous for its twists, and they tried to "one up" them for the sequel.